# Difficulty in getting exact charecters after character shuffling

Tags: java, android, arrays, data-structures, arraylist

Suppose I have a String "CAA". What I am doing now is randomly adding some Character to it for e.g. lets say I am adding Character 'B' and 'D' and  shuffle that whole Character ArrayList and placing them in some Buttons as below

[image]

Here my character ArrayList contains {'A','C','B','A','D'}

What I am trying to do is when I click on a button I want something like below [image]

I mean only keep the Buttons that contain letters of Original string and disable all other Buttons.

Comment: Those are down voting at least let me know why not useful down vote.

Comment: That's frustrating when people down vote without explaining why. Consider this as laziness of people. This behavior has now became so often on StackOverflow these days. It will for sure scare away new people joining in the community.   But here people usually look for your effort to solve your specific problem you asked. You can't bluntly ask."I want to do this. How do i do that". I up voted your question man so cheers. Hope you will get the solution and dont forget to accept correct answer or posting your own.

Comment: the random characters you add later before shuffling. Can they be similar with characters present in the original string ?

Comment: @Javanator Couldn't get you completely.But I am generating some random characters between "A" to "Z". So it might be same character or different character

Comment: Cool. That should be easily doable.Please check the answer i posted

Comment: I would simply use a custom CheckBox or CheckedTextView (without the tick mark). Easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a Custom Class that wraps a Character and a boolean flag to maintain that its original character.

   ```
    class MyCharacter {
      private Character c;
      private boolean isOriginal;

      public MyCharacter(Character c, boolean isOriginal) {
          this.c = c;
          this.isOriginal = isOriginal;
      }

      public Character getChar() {
          return c;
      }

      public boolean isOriginal() {
          return isOriginal;
      }
    }
   ```
2. Instead of adding Character into list. Add MyChracter object.
3. For original chracters pass boolean true in constructor and for later random ones pass false in it.
4. Do shuffling or whatever you want. At any moment iterate over the list. Get the MyChracter object and check whether its original or not.

This should be simple to do. 
Hope this helps

Cheers

Comment: Okk , I will let you know once I finish it , thanks ,

Answer (score 0):

You could keep several different `ArrayLists`. One holds the characters that you display, one holds the original, and then when a button is clicked test to see if a button is in the original `ArrayList` before graying it out.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to do that right now but what my problem is while for the both 'A's of String "CAA" its pointing to the same 'A'

Comment: Might you be able to test using reference equality instead of logical equality then? As long as the original `ArrayList` and the button `ArrayList` share objects that should work

Comment: Could you please provide any link which can be helpful for me ?

Comment: This might be a start: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Comparing_Objects